# In Yii2, I need to download the file that I uploaded in /web/uploads/ folder. How do i do it?

Tags: file, download, upload, yii2

Here is the the part of the view, I made a download button.

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<p>
    <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Download', ['download', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</p>
```

Here is the download function on my controller, I cant get it to work.

```
public function actionDownload($id)
    {
        $model = new Items();
        $path = Yii::getAlias('@webroot');
        $file = $path . '/' .$model->item_pathname;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
        Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
        }
    }
```

The path of the file is saved in the database's item_pathname (e.g. "/uploads/samplefile.doc". I don't know how to successfully access it to append it to the path variable. It would be of great help to solve this for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'ts not clear what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

If a download takes too much time, I see 2 possibilities

You can increase the max execution time of your script. That's not the best solution as the script will still time out for too big files but that's the simplest solution (there may be performance considerations unrelated to your question). To do so :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5*60); // 5 minutes
```

You can use the X-SendFile header of Apache (if this module in enabled in Apache only) to let Apache handle the sending of the file. More about this on Yii2 documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#sending-files. Beware of bugs in IE<=8.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
Yii::$app->response->xSendFile($file);
}
```